# how to take a number and find its alphabet position python

Tags: python, string, int, addition

So far, 
I have been able to take a letter and find it's number position. Example, `a == 0`
But now I want to take that number, and add 4. Then return the alphabet equivalent of that number. 
So, 
`a == 0; 0 + 4 = 5;` should return `f`. Cause that is fifth in the alphabet! 
Here is my code so far:

```
def convert_int(str):
    a = string.lowercase.index(str)
    addition = a +13
    return addition;
```

Comment: `string.lowercase[new_index]`

Comment: Do you mean `a = 1`, because `f = 5`? Or do you want it to start from 0, so `f = 4`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `chr()` and `ord()` functions.

```
print(ord('a'))  # 97
print(chr(97 + 4))  # e
print(chr(ord('f') + 2))  # h
```

Comment: @german Glad to help! Don't forget to accept the answer if it's satisfactory, to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

In the easy way, you can use `ord` to convert ascii character to decimal base, ex: `A` ~ 65, then you should add with any numbers which you want, and use `chr` to convert it back to ascii. Example:

`chr((ord(a) + number) % 123)`

In the harder way and popular, you should use [dict](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) in python

Answer (score 1):

```
import string

alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase
#alphabet='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

#print char by position: ex: 4 
 print(alphabet[4])
#This will print e
```